# openssl-rsa c library

Tags: c, openssl

JKJS

```
RSA_print_fp(stdout,rsa,1);
```

this function adds 0x00 in modulus . So public key size becomes 129 bytes instead of 128 bytes.
Why 0x00 is added?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modulus is an integer, not a string of bytes. An integer can be both negative and positive. Although negative integers are not used for the modulus in RSA, the functions that handle integers are generic in OpenSSL.

A negative number has its most significant bit set to 1. To distinguish between a negative integer and a positive integer that happens to have bit 7 of the most significant byte set to 1, the positive integer is prefixed with 0x00.

Answer (score 0):

It is the ASN.1 DER encoding of the modulus. Integers are represented in two's complement form, big endian order, and minimal number of bytes.

By that rule, `FF` is -1 (decimal) and`00 FF` is 255 (decimal).

In RSA, all integers are positive. Hence, the MSB bit of the leftmost byte is never set.